# issue with bootstrap styling input types

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i am using asp.net mvc-5 and i am using default bootstrap that comes with MVC template. I have issue with styling with form. Form input that is @Html.EditorFor for string value is displaying in right GUI but the integer   @Html.EditorFor is not picking up default css, additionally i have notice that is got extra CSS class ".single-line" with "text-box" class....

I want same look and feel.... what i am doing wrong!

### string value display

[image]

```
 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model._Qualification.QualificationTitle, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model._Qualification.QualificationTitle)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._Qualification.QualificationTitle)
      </div>
 </div>
```

### int value display

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model._Qualification.MinCandidates, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-6">      
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model._Qualification.MinCandidates)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._Qualification.MinCandidates)
    </div>
 </div>
```

also is there way that i can add class to EditFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use TextBoxFor, unless you create your own editor templates so you can pass class information

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._Qualification.QualificationTitle, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else use [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/). It has a lot of helpers you might find useful. Example:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model => model.Property)
```

---

Disclaimer:
BMVC is not free for Bootstrap 3.
I'm the author of BMVC